# How can I get a list of the most viewed Youtube videos of the day by region?

Tags: javascript, php, api, youtube, youtube-api

So far I can only find the following URL method of getting most_viewed videos:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/COUNTRYCODE/most_viewed

The problems with this is that youtube doesn't seem to have a region code for Denmark, nor is there any ways to look for the most_viewed video OF THE DAY. Anyone have any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use videoCategories and guideCategories for that.

[YouTube's most popular videos feed is changed](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/09/what-to-watch-our-apis-can-help.html).

[Right now the best way is to use Data API v3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcrG0_XTO9o&feature=youtu.be).